# How to dynamically create n numbers of columns?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, html-table

I would like to embellish my code a little .. this page serves as a summary to visualize the data present in my database, I would like to do so that it does not just look at one button per column but I would like to make sure to put 5 buttons for column according to a precise graphic order .. the solution that seems to me more appropriate is the use of  .. I implemented everything and the buttons are created dynamically in the right way .. the only thing is that I print every time on a new line a button ... does anyone know how to be able to put 5/4 buttons on a line and tell them to wrap automatically? 
I attach the photo of my result ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
        header('location: ../../../index.php');
    }else
    {

?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Salc!2018";
$dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT idCantiere,nomeCantiere,codiceCommessa,indirizzoCantiere FROM Cantiere";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo'<br><br><br>';
    int $cont = 0;
        echo '<table align="center" border="0px" width = "1300px">';
        echo '<tr align="center">';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        if($cont == 5)
        {
        echo '<td><a class="myButton" href="sceltaOperazione.php?idCantiere=' . $row["idCantiere"] . '">' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a></td>';
        }
        else
        {
        echo '<tr><td><a class="myButton" href="sceltaOperazione.php?idCantiere=' . $row["idCantiere"] . '">' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a></td></tr>';

        }

$cont++;
echo'</tr>';
        echo '</table>';


    echo'<br><br><br>';
        echo '<table align="center" border="1px" width = "1300px">';
        echo '<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="000035">';
        echo '<a href="../../pagineHtml/inserimento/inserimentoGenerale/inserimentoCantiere.php" class="myButton" alt="Nuovo Cantiere +">Nuovo Cantiere +</a>';
        echo '</tr></td>';
        echo '</table>';

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
//$idCantiere = $_POST["idCantiere"];



$conn->close();
?>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Progetto Cantiere</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../paginaIniziale/css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <style>

    .myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000035;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000035;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000035;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000035), color-stop(1, #000035));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000035', endColorstr='#000035',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #000035;
    border:1px solid #000035;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:32px 76px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #1570cd;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000035), color-stop(1, #000035));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #000035 5%, #000035 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000035', endColorstr='#000035',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#000035;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

    </style>

  <body>
<table align="center">
  <tr >
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                </td>
                <td style=" border-style: none" colspan="19"> <img src="../../../login/images/logo.jpg"  width="300px"  height="100px" alt="Logo SALC.SPA"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
  </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

I am attaching photo of my results ..

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OSyC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css grid or flexbox, put your buttons inside a div and style it:

```
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

You can also look at this guide to understand how it works and learn some useful attributes to customize it better: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<table align="center" border="0px" width = "1300px">';
        echo '<tr align="center">';
        echo '<td><a class="myButton" href="sceltaOperazione.php?idCantiere=' . $row["idCantiere"] . '">' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a></td>';
        echo'</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
}
```

Move everything except the `<td>` line outside of the while loop. What you currently have creates a new table for every row in the database. By moving everything out you will instead create a new column for each row.

Comment: Hello Mat, thank you for your kind reply ... actually I had thought of that solution myself ..
positioning the loop puts them all on one line .. but how can I put a limit of 5 buttons per line?

Comment: Create a count outside the loop that increments for each row and resets at 5. Use if statements to conditionally open and close rows to create a new row every 5 iterations.

Comment: int $cont = 0;
  echo '<table align="center" border="0px" width = "1300px">';
  echo '<tr align="center">';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
  if($cont == 5)
  {
  echo '<td><a class="myButton" href="sceltaOperazione.php?idCantiere=' . $row["idCantiere"] . '">' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a></td>';
  }
  else
  {
  echo '<tr><td><a class="myButton" href="sceltaOperazione.php?idCantiere=' . $row["idCantiere"] . '">' . $row["nomeCantiere"] . '</a></td></tr>';
  $cont++;
  }
  echo'</tr>';
  echo '</table>';

Comment: Please edit your question with the code formatted - it's impossible to read like that :)

Comment: you're right i added the code the principal answer, thanks

Comment: You don't seem to have closed your while loop with a `}`.